# AWS Glue Workflow marked with status `Completed` even on Glue job errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-workflow

I am creating Glue Workflow using CDK as shown below. It is composed of Glue jobs and crawlers. Is it possible to mark the status of the Workflow as `Error` when any of the components fail? Currently it is always marked as `Completed`.

```
const etlWorkflow = new glue.CfnWorkflow(this, "WorkflowId", {
    name: "WorkflowName",
});
```

Comment: This isn't just limited to using CDK - I have the same situation without it